# Words that are only used in retrospect

Tags: single-word-requests

During World War I, people did not refer to the war as "World War I" because World War II hadn't happened yet. Similarly, nobody who lived in any of the years BC ("before Christ") actually counted the years backwards using the suffix "BC".

Is there a term for words that could have never been used by those who lived in the time being referred to? It's not an "anachronism", although the usage of such a word during that time would indeed be an anachronism.

Comment: The term that will be adopted some day is **retroclature**. That's where the smart money sits, though **clionym** may ultimately prevail.

Comment: @TimR The candidate 'retroclature' was actually proposed for a totally different usage. It has virtually no presence on the internet. Why does the smart money sit there?

Comment: 'avant la lettre' is a French phrased used in English for referring to a period of time before a phrase is coined but when the phrase is appropriate (exactly those circumstances you refer to). For example, related to another question here, "The work 'The Reader Over Your Shoulder' was written in the interwar period, 'avant la lettre'." But this refers to the period in which the word 'interwar' is used, not the word itself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because the average educated speaker could probably guess the meaning of **retroclature** (e.g. BCE) whereas if they didn't know  the name of the muse of history, they'd have to look up the word **clionym**  (e.g. The Great Depression) in a dictionary.

Comment: A good guess would be 'terminology no longer used'.

Comment: It's like Star Wars all over again… There is a term for renaming things of the past (e.g. types of 'phones') when technology and/or time significantly changes the common meaning of a word (e.g. phone → smartphone). So you may want to narrow your scope somewhat.

Comment: To nitpick, the expression [First World War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I#Names) was used from 1914 although less commonly than Great War.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs My scope was actually constrained to historical indications, but now that you say it, we might as well broaden it to objects as well! Oops.

Comment: @Mew, the point of HippoSawrUs' comment is that the term for the old technologies, that were at the time the only ones available and so nobody saw the need to distinguish them from the later ones, is well established (it is *retronym*), so this question needs to be narrowed to the cases that do not involve technological changes (rather than broadened). If nobody offers a better term, one may, however, wonder whether the meaning of *retronym* could be extended to the cases that do not involve technological changes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't this the opposite of that? The question is about terminology used now that didn't exist before, because it wouldn't have made sense then.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I missed off the vocative, TimR.  Though hardly an appropriate suggestion for a SWR.  My punt at the meaning of 'retroclature'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the comments pointed out, the term *retronym* works, but it was objected that this term can only be applied in cases of technological change. This isn't true, and in fact [Wikipedia gives "World War I" as an example:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym)

> A retronym is a newer name for an existing thing that helps differentiate the original form from a more recent one. It is thus a word or phrase created to avoid confusion between older and newer types, whereas previously (before there were more than one type) no clarification was required. [...]
>
> The global war of the early 20th Century from 1914 to 1918 was referred to at the time as the "Great War". However, after World War II (also known as the Second World War) erupted in 1939, the Great War was gradually more commonly referred to instead as World War I or the First World War.

Comment: Reddit includes << ... a "retronym" being something retroactively renamed ... 



Acoustic eels were just called "eels" before the electric eel came along.....

In architecture Art Deco and Art Nouveau were called modernistic before they were named retroactively.... >>